# file_get_contents не работает из класса

Tags: php

Всем привет! Столкнулся со странной проблемой. Гружу конфиги YML, забираю файлик через file_get_contents на парсинг напрямую из индекса - все работает замечательно. А вот из-под моего класса контекста он не работает. Дошло до маразма - закомментил весь функционал, оставил пустой конструктор и сделал отдельную публичную функцию с получением файла и попытался вывести его содержимое через echo на страницу. Не работает. С чем это может быть связано? Спасибо

Comment: С тем что ты не озаботился получением сообщений об ошибках.

Answer (score 1):

file_get_content работает нормально. Просто вы не научились еще ООП. Прочитай про область видимости http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php  Возможно еще где-то ошибка - советую выложить листинг кода сюда или на pastebin.com